# Error while loading excel file into pandas : xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Workbook is encrypted

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am downloading a file using python and read it. But while reading the xls file it throws `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Workbook is encrypted`  I am able to open the file manually but not in python

My code

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

Can somebody help me on this! . I have researched a lot to crack this issue but None worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XLRD is not capable of handling file with encryption on it's own, but there is another Python library that actually can unencrypt a lot of MS Office files including the one you are trying to read .xls. It's called [msoffcrypto-tool](https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool)

Comment: But in this one i need to provide the password which i do not know

Comment: I suggest first checking if your .xls file is encrypted. You can do that with "msoffcrypto-tool document.doc --test -v"

Comment: Yes I checked it, It says encrypted

Comment: Version: 4.12.0
TestFile.xls: encrypted

Comment: I just figured out that Excel will encrypt the workbook by its self (with the fixed password "VelvetSweatshop") in order to obfuscate the protected sheets. When you open an encrypted workbook, Excel silently tries the password "VelvetSweatshop" first so it doesn't look encrypted to the user and you said that you can open the file manually. So try again to use msoffcrypto-tool to unencrypt it but with a password "VelvetSweatshop".

Comment: Excellent! I love this community. Thank you